# Why variable is not assigned sometimes?

Tags: autohotkey

I have the following script:

```
Capslock::Backspace
Var := 123
#Z::MsgBox % "Var = '" . Var . "'"
```

And when I press Win-Z it displays: `Var = ''`. If I remove first line or move it to the end of file everything works as expected. What is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assignment `Var := 123` needs to reside in the "Auto-execute Section" for it to execute. Specifically, it needs to precede any hotkey definitions.

From [Autohotkey Documentation > Scripts](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm):

> After the script has been loaded, it begins executing at the top line,
>   continuing until a Return, Exit, hotkey/hotstring label, or the
>   physical end of the script is encountered (whichever comes first).
>   This top portion of the script is referred to as the auto-execute
>   section.